# Can't pause / sleep thread inside for loop

Tags: android, multithreading, sleep

How can i sleep thread, from inside of for loop .

This is what i'm trying but there is no sleep .

```
Thread newTread = new Thread() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int x = 0; x < limit; x++) {

            //some_code

            try {
                 Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                 e.getLocalizedMessage();
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //someCode       
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    newTread.start();
```

Is there something wrong with my code ?

Comment: Two things. Firstly, `e.getLocalizedMessage()` isn't the common way to handle exceptions, as this does not provide all the information you might need to fix your problem. Use e.printStackTrace(). Secondly, we can't know what's wrong with your code, as nothing seems to be. There's quite a couple things we don't know here. Is your limit variable set to at least 1? Does the run actually run? Try inserting `Log.d("thread","somemessage 1");` at a couple points in your code (with the 1 being replaced by 1,2,3, 4 etc) and post back the output that gives you, when you do that we might be able to help.

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg thanks for what you say about exeptions . and yes the code run perfect and limit is set to more than 1. and when i put Log after `try' i see the Log inside LogCat

Comment: And if you put it right after the sleep, do you see them appear with the expected 3 second interval, or does the code skip over the sleep?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've gone ahead and thrown the code into a project of my own, with some added debugging code. Here's the code I used and output I received.

```
    Thread newTread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {

                Log.d("ThreadTest","1");

                try {
                    Log.d("ThreadTest","2");
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    Log.d("ThreadTest", "3");
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.d("ThreadTest","4");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void run() {
                                      Log.d("ThreadTest","5");
                                  }
                              });
            }
        }
    };
    newTread.start();
```

> 11-04 08:23:38.920 11419-11452/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer 
>   D/ThreadTest: 1 11-04 08:23:38.920
>   11419-11452/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 2 11-04 08:23:41.920
>   11419-11452/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 3 11-04 08:23:41.920
>   11419-11452/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 4 11-04 08:23:41.920
>   11419-11452/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 1 11-04 08:23:41.920
>   11419-11452/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 2 11-04 08:23:41.920
>   11419-11419/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 5 11-04 08:23:44.920
>   11419-11452/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 3 11-04 08:23:44.920
>   11419-11452/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 4 11-04 08:23:44.920
>   11419-11452/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 1 11-04 08:23:44.920
>   11419-11452/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 2 11-04 08:23:44.920
>   11419-11419/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 5 11-04 08:23:47.920
>   11419-11452/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 3 11-04 08:23:47.920
>   11419-11452/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 4 11-04 08:23:47.920
>   11419-11419/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 5

In my case the code did actually wait for three seconds, so nothing seems wrong with that. What is interesting to note, however, is the fact that the "5" can appear **after** the next 1. This is because of the way runOnUiThread works. What it does, is it puts the runnable you provide on a queue. From this queue, android will grab one runnable at a time and run it when the Ui thread has time to run it. This means that, if you were to do something like this:

```
    newTread.start();
    boolean a = true;
    while (a){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
            a = a;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

you'll get a log like:

> 11-04 08:27:51.810
>   14909-14942/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 1 11-04 08:27:51.815
>   14909-14942/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 2 11-04 08:27:54.815
>   14909-14942/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 3 11-04 08:27:54.815
>   14909-14942/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 4 11-04 08:27:54.815
>   14909-14942/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 1 11-04 08:27:54.815
>   14909-14942/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 2 11-04 08:27:57.815
>   14909-14942/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 3 11-04 08:27:57.815
>   14909-14942/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 4 11-04 08:27:57.815
>   14909-14942/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 1 11-04 08:27:57.815
>   14909-14942/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 2 11-04 08:28:00.815
>   14909-14942/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 3 11-04 08:28:00.815
>   14909-14942/nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.bootsnelleinvoer
>   D/ThreadTest: 4

Note that there isn't a single 5 in there. This is because the UI-thread is too busy to execute the stack. I'm guessing this is exactly what's happening to you.

My recommendation for fixing this: [Breakpoints](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html). Try to figure out if, and if so where, your UI thread is hanging, and solve that. This code functions as it should.

Answer (score -1):

Please note the **comments in the source code** below, they will tell you how everything works.

```
private void waitForWifi() {
        mProgressDialog = new Dialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).show();

        // creating a thread to wait until the connection is established
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!Utils.isConnected(MainActivity.this)) {
                     // we wait until condition is matching to fit our needs   
                     Thread.sleep(300); 
                     // Do NOT(!) use "sleep(1);" <- pure waste of battery    
                     // and won't in 99,9% of the situa. make your app better!
                    }
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    // perform a new action
        };
        t.start();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution. (Also, what comments?)

Comment: See the comments in the code. What would be the benefit if I write "Do NOT(!) use Thread.sleep(1);" outside the code? The person who asked the question has to double-check if his code applies the correct behaviour to his app. So at that point he should be able to recognize how important a comment as "we wait until condition is matching to fit our needs" is. That pauses the action... Not really rocket science.

Comment: The frame of "Maybe you are achieving this", which makes no sense at all, is probably what's throwing me off.